# Finalizar Processo C# Mono

Tags: c#

Bom dia, tenho um método que fecha a aplicação quando altero as configurações no windows, porém no sistema linux o mesmo não finaliza o processo segue abaixo o código.

```
        if (strProcesso.Trim() == "")
        {
            if (getSO() == enumPlataformaSO.Windows)
            {
                strProcesso = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
                intQtdeProc = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("mono-sgen"))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    return false;
                }

                strProcesso = "mono-sgen";
                intQtdeProc = 0;
            }
        }
```

como posso resolver está questão?

Comment: Ele não fecha ou não encontra o processo pelo nome?

Comment: ele não encontra o processo para ser finalizado conforme mostrado no código, no windows funciona perfeitamente e o sistema e finalizado, porém no linux ele não faz nada.

Comment: Não é permissão de usuário ou o `_` ao invés do `-`? Verificou se ele de fato está sendo listado na `Process.GetProcesses()`?

Comment: não está sendo listado

Comment: Aparentemente  com os teste feito ele está sem permissão como atribuo as permissões de usuario no código